# Best place(mount folder) to keep media files on hard drive

Tags: partitioning, mount, hard-drive, xbmc

I would like to keep all my Movies and TVShow files in two separate folders and keep them on a separate partition/drive. Also integrating theme with XBMC. ALso having flexibility to remove the extra harddisk to be used as portable drive.

Earlier i used to keep everything in separate partition, with mount /home. This meant that everthing including userfiles, downloads etc ended up on separate partition.

Now i have mount my files (Movies and TVShows) with name /media . 
This method seems very convenient, with auto mount setup this should work with without any problem. But I have noticed that sometimes after fresh starup the files do appear in xbmc and torrent client. After spending few mins and opening the folders using file browser and restarting the applications this gets solved.

Leading me to wonder what is best and most appropriate place (mount , partition) to keep huge media files like movies etc on linux.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Leading me to wonder what is best and most appropriate place (mount , partition) to keep huge media files like movies etc on linux.

Basically ... wherever *you* want.

If you want to keep it as intended...

1. `/media/` is intended for **removeable media** so not to mount an internal disk/partition.
2. `/mnt/` is intended for a temporarily mounted filesystem
3. `/home/` is intended for users and their documents.

I tend to use a custom partition. All my stuff is in `/discworld/`. Makes it easy to recognize during a re-install. And makes it easy to backup.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to preface this answer by clarifying that anytime you ask what's the best way to do anything, you are asking people their OPINION.  I recently got in trouble on this site for posting opinion, and so I suppose if I were wise I'd keep my mouth shut.  Guess I'm not wise.

I declare that in my honest opinion, the BEST way is THE UBUNTU WAY...

By default, Ubuntu prenames several folders for Documents, Downloads, Music, and Pictures.  In the olden days, MS Windows never did anything like this, and as soon as they did, they didn't produce a file hierarchy which benefited technicians legitimate attempts to back up client data;  I should know, I was one of them.

These days the default hierarchy of personal user data is pretty similar between Ubuntu and Windows, and this help everyone because even minimally indoctrinated technicians can find and backup user data without too much trouble.

In addition, Ubuntu gives you the ability to not only add new folders to your home folder, but within the Nautilus file browser, you can easily add what it calls "bookmarks" which appear in the same left side lineup, even if they are on entirely separate drives.  Imagine moving the hard drive from your older computer to your current one and instead of copying the files over, you simply bookmark the most important folders into your file browser!

Please note that, for better or worse nautilus bookmarks will not be visible if you browse the drive with another file browser such as [Gnome Commander](https://gcmd.github.io/), for example.  Links however appear to be independent of the file browser used.